# Monkeypatching: calling the original mocked method after changing some of its arguments

Tags: python, pytest, monkeypatching

We want to test a function that reads some data file (`data_file.dat`) located in the package data. A simplified version of this function looks like:

```
import pkg_resources


def get_data_file_content():
    data_file_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename("mymodule", "data/data_file.dat")
    with open(data_file_path, 'r') as f:
        return f.read()
```

Our project is structured as follows:

```
myproject
├───mymodule
│   ├───data
│   │   └───data_file.dat
│   ├───data_provider.py
│   └───__main__.py
├───tests
│   ├───data
│   │   └───data_file.dat
│   └───test_data_provider.py
└───setup.py
```

We want to use the package data directory in the tests package whenever running a test.

To do so, we want to stub the calls to `pkg_resources` and change the first argument. We managed to do so using the following (`test_data_provider.py`):

```
from mymodule.data_provider import get_data_file_content


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_pkg_resources(monkeypatch):
    original_method = pkg_resources.resource_filename

    def resource_filename_stub(_, file_name):
        return original_method("tests", file_name)

    monkeypatch.setattr(pkg_resources, "resource_filename", resource_filename_stub)


def test_get_data_file_content():
    data = get_data_file_content()
    assert data == "test data (the content does not matter)"
```

Is there a better way to achieve this rather than creating an alias for the stubbed method, or is there other recommendations in general to replace the package data in tests?